# Image not Showing in Template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an image in a page but I keep getting

```
AttributeError: 'Setting' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I have used Images several times in other models the same project but I don't know what I might be missing here

Here is the Models.py

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    about_text = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="About Us Text")
    about_image = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, upload_to='Marketing', verbose_name="About Us Image")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

Here is the views

```
def who_we_are(request):
    setting = Setting.objects.get()
    template = 'who_we_are.html'
    context = {'setting': setting}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here is the template

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}
       <div class="view" style="background-image: url('{{ setting.get_image_url }}');></div>
      <div class="container pt-4">
        {{setting.about_text|safe}}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: in get_image_url there is string named self.image though there is no image field in Settings class that is the reason it showing you this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- improve this
- modify `self.image` to `self.about_image` in model

```
def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, self.about_image)
```